# Phoenix Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

On my post model, I have implemented a simple validation

```
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_length(:content, min: 2)
    |> validate_length(:content, max: 500)
  end
```

On submitting the Post create form the view, I would like to show errors if there was something wrong from user submission, here is the view that renders the error

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below:</p>
      <ul>
        <%= for {attr, message} <- f.errors do %>
          <%IEx.pry%>
          <li><%= humanize(attr) %> <%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I am getting this error `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for {"should be at least %{count} character(s)", [count: 2]}
        (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/safe.ex:74: Phoenix.HTML.Safe.Tuple.to_iodata/1`

I cant find out why this is happening, I had a similar validation in another phoenix app(also in the phoenix docs) that worked perfectly

**Update** - The earlier app was using using an older Ecto and phoenix version , I am currently on Ecto 2.0 + and Phoenix 1.1,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to show the error message in a Changeset is to use [`MyApp.ErrorHelpers.translate_error/1`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/7e490ea2565d96048e82bdf9f27c0d32295e3d37/installer/templates/new/web/views/error_helpers.ex#L17-L38).

Replace:

```
<li><%= humanize(attr) %> <%= message %></li>
```

with

```
<li><%= humanize(attr) %> <%= translate_error(message) %></li>
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> MyApp.ErrorHelpers.translate_error {"should be at least %{count} character(s)", [count: 2]}
"should be at least 2 character(s)"
```

Comment: Thank You, I had not realized my app was using Ecto 2.0

Comment: I believe it was added in Phoenix 1.1 along with Gettext (http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-v10-to-v11) and is not related to Ecto 2.0.

Comment: I see, I did copy the template from an older version of phoenix, thanks

Comment: You probably upgraded Phoenix too. I ran the above "Demo" on a Phoenix 1.1 + Ecto 1.1.8 app.